# Nuxt 3 and Express.js: On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'd:' (ESM Loader Problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

i do not know whether this question is a clone or similar, but most that i see have @nuxt/robot integrated in it but mine does not so....,

I get the following error when i want to start my nuxt 3 with express.js project:

```
[worker reload] [worker init] Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'd:'

  at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:496:5)
  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
  at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/load:131:11)
  at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:82:3)
  at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
  at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:603:26)
  at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
  at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
  at #createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
  at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34)
  at async ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:79:21)
```

these are my
nuxt.config.ts:

```
import{resolve} from "path"
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  alias:{
    "@": resolve(__dirname,"/"),
  },
  modules:['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
  extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.ts', '.vue', '.json', '.commonjs-external'],
})
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "^1.0.2",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^3.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.9.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "nuxt": "^3.8.1",
    "vue": "^3.3.8",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/nitro": "^0.10.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nuxt3": "^3.8.0-28284309.b3d3d7f4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "transformers": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 18.12.1"
  }
}
```

Additional Information:
Node.js: v18.17.1
Nuxt 3.8.1 with Nitro 2.7.2
but not using nitro
Using WIndows 10

,i tried setting

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
```

in cmder and run the code there but the error still came up and referenced other solution but end up nothing but errors